# How can I separate two panels bonded with urethane glue?

Tags: wood, adhesive, removal

I glued a painting wood panel back to another small piece of wood to add hanging wire with gorilla glue.  I now want to take these two wood pieces apart.  What can I use?

Comment: A sharp chizzle or exactO knife will work gorilla glue is really tough once expanded and set.

Comment: Gorilla glue is polyurethane, so give a look for anything that will dissolve it without destroying your project. Ed's comment is probably the best bet, though. "Chizzle". :D

Comment: As they say in NJ, "Fuhgeddaboudit!"

Answer (score 1):

A saw, a chisel, or brute force. Cured polyurethane glue is largely impervious to solvents, and if there are any exceptions to that, they are probably absurdly hazardous to people.

If you don't actually want the small piece, setting up a router jig to plane it off the painting would be a relatively tidy/controlled way of removing it.